# Load Div after Jquery Slide is complete not working

Tags: jquery, user-interface

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#imgscroll_right').live('click', function(e){
     $('#img_holder').hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 1000, function() {
      $('#pictures_wrapper').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' #pictures_container' );          
     });
     e.preventDefault(); 
   }); 
});
```

The div `#img_holder` does slide, but nothing happens with `#pictures_wrapper`.  What I'm trying to do is load the div `#pictures_wrapper` after the effect on `#img_holder` is complete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I figured it out, had an error with HTML.  OOPS!!